# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'

Tags: javascript, frontend

Everything looks fine with this small piece of code as shown in the screenshot. Yet, I am getting the syntax error around `{`. Please tell me what might be causing it?

[image]

Comment: this is your custom code?

Comment: Yes, it is. I am keeping a check here before calling a function defined in some other JS file.

Comment: can you upload js code here? then i check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive. Just change "If" to "if".

Examples:

- This works: `if (1) { console.log('hey') }`
- This doesn't work: `If (1) { console.log('hey') }`